# Share folder and access this folder on different domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain

the following situations:

i have two pc's. My work desktop with XP prof and logged on in domain mywork.com. This desktop also has two network card. one for logging on the mywork.com domain and using the intranet etc. this desktop also has a network card with access to a switch.

the other pc is a windows 7 prof pc. with is logged in to workgroup domain and also access the switch.

now i want to access a shared folder from XP with my 7. but this is not possible because XP is in a different domain. 7 is asked for a user and password but i can't fill in my "mywork.com" login.

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create a local user account on the XP
  workstation (right-click My Computer
  -> Manage -> Users).
- Add that user account onto the NTFS
  and Share permissions.
- When prompted for the username/password,
  enter the username in the format XPMACHINENAME\LOCALUSERNAME

Comment: this works perfect! thx

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do that. You can use a UPN (like you@mywork.com) or a standard Windows domain (MYWORK\you or whatever).

From the command line, you can use the /u switch to "net use". Say I'm on a machine in the CORP domain (logged in with a CORP domain account) and I want to access a resource shared by a machine in the GALILEO domain. All I need to do is:

```
net use * \\galileo-machine\someShare /u:galileo\paulr
```

The net utility will obediently prompt you for a password; give it your GALILEO password and you're done.

You can do the same thing directly with the UNC path if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

true

A more tedious way is to open a new text file and add the following contents:

```
@echo off
net use U: /d /y
net use U: \\*XP-Machine*\*Share* /user:*mywork*\*michel* *password*
```

Save the newly created text file onto the desktop (of course substituting the required information), change the suffix of file from `.txt` to `.bat`, then, whenever you desire the share - double click the batch file.

To make it more 'user-friendly', place the batch file in a folder you create on your Wins 7 C: drive, make a shortcut to the desktop, Right click the shortcut and select 'properties', then select 'change icon', 'ok' to the pop-up warning, and change to a more user friendly image to help recognise the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use WORKGROUP authentication, same accounts (and passwords) existing on both machines. E.g. Create the account you use on your Win7 workstation on the XP domain client (you might have to tweak the XP security policy - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y5b4b4f.aspx)

Comment: i don't understand this. on the xp machine i don't have the domain 'WORKGROUP' and i can't create a new user in this domain...

Comment: Your XP workstation isn't in a domain is it? It is just in a Workgroup?

Workgroup authentication requires that trusted accounts exist on both the client and target. In your case the client is the Win7 PC and the target is the XP workstation.

Comment: no the XP workstation is in a domain